# Can we say that QEMU is a Virtual Machine?

Tags: virtualization, qemu

What I perceive as a Virtual Machine is that it simply allows to load another Operating System side-by-side on its own sandboxed environment.
It is limited to the same hardware architecture as the host Operating System.
With Intel VT (and similar), one can run the 64-bit version of an Operating System on a 32-bit host.

Examples of this is are VirtualBox and VMWare.

But QEMU is a Hardware Emulator: it emulates an entire computer and (may) emulate an entire architecture with every single piece emulated.
This is not limited to the same architecture.
We can run the ARM version of Linux on QEMU running on a x64 CPU.

The Android SDK uses QEMU to emulate tablets and phones for testing.

Posing this, can we say that QEMU is a virtual machine?

---

This generated a lot of discussion in the comment on the question "[How to prevent network administrators from accessing USB drive](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/83393/56707)" on another website, in which there was a 'dispute' that an Hardware Emulator is still a Virtual Machine.

Comment: @jdlugosz Thanks for the edit. You are right, it should be "its".

Comment: @jdlugosz - You submitted a sloppy edit by modifying this statement: *"Examples of **this is** are"*

Comment: @Ramhound I didn't noticed that, or I would have improved the edit

Comment: Sorry.  I was just "trying to find something else to improve" as prompted.

Comment: @jdlugosz You did, you just forgot to 'eat' a few letters.

Comment: Ah, I've had that trouble once before in the rich text box.  It looks like I backspaced but after reflowing I see they are really still there.

Comment: I see, that referenced thread had a poster saying that... his statement is completely wrong.  Unless he is using a specialized jargon (possible, since he is being very precise) but it's still wrong as he didn't declare which language he is using.  See opening paragraph in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine

Answer (score 0):

A virtual machine is *not* implying special hardware support for efficient virtualization and using the same instruction set.

VMWare translates code to run 8086 real mode in a 64-bit host.
PC Emulator on PowerPC was software translation to a different instruction set.
Java Virtual Machine is an abstraction implemented in software, seemingly a CPU and architecture.
[MAME](http://mamedev.org/) is a set of virtual machines that are classic arcade consoles, which include various CPUs and special graphics and sound chips and other novel chipset features.

An Emulator is a Virtual Machine in the scientific sense, so they are synonyms.
In common informal usage, it implies that the thing being emulated is "a machine", a complete device that may also exist as a hardware instance.  But that is kind of fuzzy.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I got lost on the answer. I still don't know if it should or should be 'called' a Virtual Machine or not.

Comment: A synonym in the English language means that both words can be used in the place of.  This means that a virtual machine is an emulator.  It also means an emulator is a virtual machine.  Its sort like saying "a dog is a K9" and "a K9 is a dog".

Comment: Check out http://www.thesaurus.com/ .   And look at the “Grammar note” at the [bottom of this page](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/synonym)

Comment: Also, common usage does not always follow *correct* usage, or technical jargon adopts a common word to have a highly precise meaning.

Comment: @Ramhound A 'k9' is a dog, but a trained dog for the police force

Comment: K9s are also domestic canines ( i.e. dogs ).

Comment: @Ramhound That's slang, but not the right usage of the word. As far as I know. (I advise against searching for k9 on Google!)